# Is there a way to remove sharing of records implemented via apex?

Tags: apex, apex-managed-sharing

I want to rollback the sharing of records implemented by creating OpportunityShare records via apex code. Initially, I had assigned specific users access to the Opportunity records, but on testing it, somehow the result is not what I had expected.Is it possible to remove that sharing?